# Unit testing call to angular service causes request for template

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-service

I am learning Angular and I wrote a simple app and have now got unit tests in jasmine for the controller and the service.

I noticed that initially my tests failed because somehow there is stil a request for /partials/calculator.html even though the test does not involve any navigation but just a direct call to a service function.

I had to add this to my beforeEach function to fix it:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('partials/calculator.html').respond(200, '');
```

Here is my app.js class:

```
 var calculatorApp = angular.module('calculatorApp', [
 'config',
 'ngRoute',  
 'calculatorControllers', 
 'calculatorServices'
]);

 calculatorApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/calculator', {
         templateUrl: 'partials/calculator.html',
         controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'
     }).
     when('/about', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
       controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/calculator'
      });
   }]);
```

Below is my entire test but could someone explain why calling a method on the service which just makes a rest call to my backend server will create this request?

```
 'use strict';

describe('service', function() {

 // load modules
beforeEach(module('calculatorApp'));

var service, httpBackend, data, url;

beforeEach(inject(function(CalculatorService, _$httpBackend_, API_URL) {
    url = API_URL;
    service = CalculatorService;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    httpBackend.whenGET('partials/calculator.html').respond(200, '');
}));

// Test service availability
it('check the existence of calculator service', function() {
  expect(service).toBeDefined();
});     


it ('should return data when calling add', function() {

      httpBackend.expectGET(url + 'calculator/add?val1=1&val2=32').respond({"result": 5});   

      service.add(1, 32).then(function(response) {            
          data = response;
      });

      httpBackend.flush();

      expect(data).toBe(5);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      // make sure all requests where handled as expected.
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    });
});
```

Comment: does your 'calculatorApp' module have routing configuration(ngRoute or ui-router)?

Comment: Yes it does, I have updated the question